# What is required to be able to use Debug.Assert() function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, assert

When I try to use Debug.Assert() within my C++ code in Visual Studio 2019 it is not recognising this class and states "identifier "Debug" is unidentified".

I am new to C++ and I discovered this function in a Microsoft Visual Studio article on debugging tools, however, it only shows its implementation but does not mention having to include any libraries to do so. I have searched a lot for why this might not work and have gotten nowhere with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Debug.Assert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=netframework-4.8) is a method in C# which is a completely different language than C++ even though Visual Studio supports both.

C++ has [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) in `<cassert>` (borrowed from C).